# How to Move a First-Person Object in the Facing Direction? (C++)

Tags: c++, math

I'm making a basic DOOM recreate in Bullet and would like to know how to move in the direction my object is facing.

Currently my framework is set-up where my camera sets its rotation and position to the player, who's position and rotation is set to the physics body created by Bullet.

Here's my current movement code for the player's movement:

```
GameObject::Update( deltatime );

if( m_pController == 0 )
    return;

vec3 dir(0, 0, 0);
vec3 rot(0, 0, 0);

if( m_pController->IsButtonPressed( PCB_Up ) )
    dir.z += 1;
if( m_pController->IsButtonPressed( PCB_Down ) )
    dir.z -= 1;
if( m_pController->IsButtonPressed( PCB_Left ) )
    dir.x -= 1;
if( m_pController->IsButtonPressed( PCB_Right ) )
    dir.x += 1;
if (m_pController->IsButtonPressed(PCB_RotLeft))
    rot.y -= 1;
if (m_pController->IsButtonPressed(PCB_RotRight))
    rot.y += 1;

dir.Normalize();
rot.Normalize();

float speed = 10.0f;

btVector3 force = btVector3(dir.x, dir.y, dir.z) * speed;
btVector3 rotForce = btVector3(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z) * speed;
if( m_pBody )
{
    m_pBody->applyForce( force, btVector3(0,0,0) );
    m_pBody->applyTorque(rotForce);

    m_pBody->forceActivationState( DISABLE_DEACTIVATION );
}
```

I know it can be done by creating a matrix from my camera and extracting my view but the thing is my camera is being set to my player's rotation and translation.

Can the same be done by creating an SRT matrix with my physics body's values and calculating a direction vector from those numbers and then have:

```
if( m_pController->IsButtonPressed( PCB_Up ) )
    dir += ForwardFacing;
if( m_pController->IsButtonPressed( PCB_Down ) )
    dir -= ForwardFacing;
```

I'm not sure how it'd be done for left and right keys though.

Anyways,
thanks for your time!

Comment: You're just asking how to take your facing vector, and calculate the normal for strafing direction, right?

Comment: Isnt this a simple cross product of the facing-vec and the up-vec then?

Comment: Yes, but since the angle between the facing and the strafe direction are 90° one could just add/substract to/from the forwardfacing rotation??

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so I just ended up putting the Object in an SRT matrix and extracting its looking at position then multiplying it by the dir.z and adding the getRight for turning and moving on the x axis.

```
mat4 mat;
mat.CreateSRT(m_Scale, m_Rotation, m_Position);

vec3 forceDir = mat.GetAt() * dir.z + mat.GetRight()*dir.x;

btVector3 force = btVector3(forceDir.x, forceDir.y, forceDir.z) * speed;
btVector3 rotForce = btVector3(rot.x, rot.y, rot.z) * speed;
```